# Connecting power supply outputs in parallel

Tags: power-supply, parallel, connect

I would like to know if it is safe to connect in parallel the outputs of a power supply like [this](https://www.efectoled.com/es/comprar-alimentacion-led-exterior/202-fuente-alimentacion-p150t-24v.html), and in case it is feasable, how to proceed.

Comment: From the image on the case, it looks like they are probably internally connected, so this probably doesn't buy you anything to connect them together.

Comment: That link is blocked for some of us. Please include the relevant content (image, screenshot, datasheet link etc) into your question, so that the question doesn't become meaningless if that site dies.

Comment: @RonBeyer it might buy you something if the load needs more current than each output can produce. Those wires look a bit thin for 6.25A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the answer is no, unless the power supply specifically states that multiple units can be connected in parallel.  Power supplies that have this capability have additional circuitry/controls to ensure that the load is being shared equally between the supplies.

What could happen if the supply is not designed for parallel operation is that one power supply ends up by driving current into the other one, a back feed of sorts.

Comment: OP is asking about connecting the two outputs of a _single_ power supply together. The power supply is question is designated as an 'LED driver' but appears to be just be a 24V regulated power supply with 2 identical outputs.

Comment: Got it.  But again, without knowing the specifics of the PS and each of it's outputs (are they from different power trains, or just two outputs from the same power train), I still caution against that given the caveats above.