# Multiple MPPT (Parallel)

Tags: dc-dc-converter, mppt

We are developing a system with multiple MPPTs connected in parallel. Now I have 2 separate MPPTs based on the Genasun GVB-8 only working if I combine them together then I get backflow current and my power supply shutdown. I don't want to use diodes so can someone explain to me how I can solve this in software/hardware. I have made a test setup with a Genasun GVB-8 and these MPPTs can be connected parallel to each other. Who has the tip for me?

[image: MPPT Schematic]
[image: Situation before connection]
[image: Situation after connection]

Comment: Explain it with more details. The MPPT is a StepUp regulator and a backflow is there not possible. Can you paint a little circuit diagram and show how you have connected your MPPT and PV-modules? Then you get better and fast answers from the people here.

Comment: Update schematic and circuit diagram how i tested & connected it

Comment: What type of MOSFET driver are you using? You should add a diode over Q8 and adjust a delay for the MOSFET Q8. Do you have measured the current flow? Oscilloscope available?

Comment: @MikroPower I am using an IR2104 mosfet driver. This will be adjusted in a next version because the rise and fall time are much too high. At 5A my mosfets get very hot because of the switching losses. But that's not important for now. So you're saying a diode across Q8 will solve the problem? The genasun GVB-8 also has this diode so I'm going to try to put it on

Comment: But what is the reason a diode across Q8 is going to help? I also saw the diode with the Genasun but don't understand the reason behind it

Comment: If you make it in this way, that the MOSFET do not switch on so fast, then there would not be any current flow, because of this the diodes are uses. After a short delay time, the MOSFET is switching on and the current can flow over the MOSFET and not the diode any more.  But you need an MOSFET driver with adjustable death-time. Normally the voltage can not be different, because the MPPT-StepUp is always adjusting the output in a way so that the input current will flow.

Comment: Almost identical deleted question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/658671/mppt-connected-in-parallel-to-a-battery

Comment: If you want your power supplies to operate in parallel, you may have picked the wrong supplies.  There are special design techniques used to insure that multiple power trains in parallel "play nicely together".  There have been numerous Q&A's on this site that discuss this matter.

Comment: @SteveSh Do you have a link to any Q&A?

Comment: @Jasper - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/485703/connecting-power-supply-outputs-in-parallel/485706#485706

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way that this could be done would be to put DC to DC isolators on the output of both mppt circuits.

Another thing that usually needs to happen when sharing power supplies is putting a small amount of resistance on the outputs of both supplies that helps them match their voltage and the drawback is a small resistive drop.

It would be pretty difficult to balance these circuits with the MPPT algorithm and power especially if the solar panels were not balanced. I have designed mppt circuit once, to do a multi-channel one I would think you would have to measure the power of both circuits and ensure that the voltage output was the same. In other words the mppt circuit has to support paralleling.